# Highcharts xAxis values index

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts but we need to get the index of the categories on the xAxis.
Is there any way to get the index of each value (Category) on the xAxis.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the categories through: `chart.xAxis[0].categories`. To get a specific category index use:

```
chart.xAxis[0].categories.indexOf('categoryName');
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nosg3b6e/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#categories

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying to use this in a tooltip so I need it dynamically computed something like : headerFormat: '<img src="/images/love6.jpg" style="height:100px" /><br />► Listing {point.x}<br />' + chart.xAxis[0].categories.indexOf(point.x), I tried this but does not work.

Comment: Hi @user2981411, You need to create the whole tooltip by using: the`tooltip.formatter` function.

Comment: I have - but it doesen't work : tooltip: {
                   
                    useHTML: true,
                    headerFormat: '<img src="/images/love6.jpg" width="150"/><br />► Listing {point.x}<br />' + chart.xAxis[0].categories.indexOf(point.x),
                  
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">► {series.name} : </span> {point.y:, .0f} <br />',
                    split: false,
                    shared: true
                }

Comment: I mean the `formatter` function (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter), not the `headerFormat` and `pointFormat` options. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/690duf3b/